# how to query from web to excel with power query

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

how to query from web to excel with power query. I tried but no table appears in power query is there an error or there is another solution with vba or else.

Thanks

[image: Capture1]
[image: Capture2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't see any table because you didn't provide any credentials and Excel isn't logged into your account.

Comment: Thank you for reply from you and how I do log in account with Power Query Excel